# Summarization pipeline with quantized model breaks after saving to disk

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, summarization

I am developing an application which uses [sshleifer/distilbart-cnn-12-6](https://huggingface.co/sshleifer/distilbart-cnn-12-6) Hugging Face model for generating text summary. Big model size is a problem for my application so I've decided to use PyTorch's [dynamic quantization](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/dynamic_quantization.html) to reduce it a little bit. After applying the quantization I experience a weird behavior. The model breaks  when I save and re-load it from disk. Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug in `transformers`? I can add that I didn't expect such problems with another model ([nateraw/bert-base-uncased-emotion](https://huggingface.co/nateraw/bert-base-uncased-emotion)).

```py
>>> import torch  # version 1.8.1+cpu
>>> from transformers import pipeline  # version 4.5.1
>>> sample_text = """
The Queen has conducted her first in-person royal duty since her husband, 
the Duke of Edinburgh, died on Friday. The monarch hosted a ceremony in which 
the Earl Peel formally stood down as Lord Chamberlain, whose office organises
royal ceremonies. During a private event held at Windsor Castle, the Queen
accepted her former royal aide's wand and office insignia. The Royal Family is
observing two weeks of mourning. The duke's funeral will take place at Windsor
on Saturday. A royal official said members of the family would continue "to 
undertake engagements appropriate to the circumstances".
"""
>>> p = pipeline("summarization", model="sshleifer/distilbart-cnn-12-6")
>>> quantized_model = torch.quantization.quantize_dynamic(
    p.model,
    {torch.nn.Linear},
    dtype=torch.qint8
)
>>> quantized_pipeline = pipeline("summarization", model=quantized_model, tokenizer=p.tokenizer)
>>> quantized_pipeline(sample_text)
[{'summary_text': ' The Queen has been in the spotlight for the first time in the past week . During a private event at Windsor Castle, the Queen was at the centre of the royal family . The Queen is the Queen, and the Queen has a lot to do well, but the Queen is in the news this week .'}]
>>> quantized_pipeline.save_pretrained("/tmp/my_model")
>>> loaded_pipeline = pipeline("summarization", model="/tmp/my_model")
>>> loaded_pipeline(sample_text)
[{'summary_text': ' high high highhighhighhigh high high High High HighHighHighHigh high high highest highest highest lowest lowest lowest highest highesthighesthighesthighest highest highest Highest Highest Highesthighesthighest lowest lowest lows lows highs highs highs lows lows lows low low lowlowlowlow low lowLowLowLow low low lowest lowest safest safest safest safe safe safesafesafesafe safe safe safest safest safer safer safer safe safe secure secure secure secured secured secured secure securesecuresecuresecure secure secureSecureSecureSecure secure secure securing securing securing secured secured securing securing secure secure Secure Secure Secure secure secure obtain obtain obtain obtained obtained obtained obtain obtain obtaining obtaining obtaining obtain obtain attain attain attain obtain obtainGetGetGet Get Get GetGetGet get get get Get'}]
```

The summary generated after quantization is not very good but it has something in common with the input text. What I'm getting after saving the model and re-loading from disk is pure garbage.

There's also a warning displayed when I'm loading the model from disk (no such message when instantiating `quatized_pipeline` though):

```
Some weights of the model checkpoint at /tmp/my_model were not used when initializing BartForConditionalGeneration: ['model.encoder.layers.0.self_attn.k_proj.scale', 'model.encoder.layers.0.self_attn.k_proj.zero_point', 'model.encoder.layers.0.self_attn.k_proj._packed_params.dtype', 'model.encoder.layers.0.self_attn.k_proj._packed_params._packed_params', 'model.encoder.layers.0.self_attn.v_proj.scale', 'model.encoder.layers.0.self_attn.v_proj.zero_point', 'model.encoder.layers.0.self_attn.v_proj._packed_params.dtype', 'model.encoder.layers.0.self_attn.v_proj._packed_params._packed_params', 'model.encoder.layers.0.self_attn.q_proj.scale', 'model.encoder.layers.0.self_attn.q_proj.zero_point', 'model.encoder.layers.0.self_attn.q_proj._packed_params.dtype', 'model.encoder.layers.0.self_attn.q_proj._packed_params._packed_params', 'model.encoder.layers.0.self_attn.out_proj.scale', 'model.encoder.layers.0.self_attn.out_proj.zero_point', 'model.encoder.layers.0.self_attn.out_proj._packed_params.dtype', 'model.encoder.layers.0.self_attn.out_proj._packed_params._packed_params', 'model.encoder.layers.0.fc1.scale', 'model.encoder.layers.0.fc1.zero_point', 'model.encoder.layers.0.fc1._packed_params.dtype', 'model.encoder.layers.0.fc1._packed_params._packed_params', 'model.encoder.layers.0.fc2.scale', 'model.encoder.layers.0.fc2.zero_point', 'model.encoder.layers.0.fc2._packed_params.dtype', 'model.encoder.layers.0.fc2._packed_params._packed_params', ...]
You should probably TRAIN this model on a down-stream task to be able to use it for predictions and inference.
```